# How do I filter multiple values in array

Tags: arrays, loops, filter, conditional-statements, array-filter

`const arr1 = [{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5}]`
`const arr2 = [{Id:2},{id:4}]`

I want to filter arr1 that contains arr2.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function will return elements arr1 not contained arr2

```js
const arr1 = [{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5}] 
const arr2 = [{id:2},{id:4}]

const arrayFilter = (arr1, arr2) => {
  
  return arr1.filter( (item) => {
    return ((JSON.stringify(arr2)).indexOf(JSON.stringify(item)) <= 0) ? item : false
   })
}

console.log(arrayFilter(arr1,arr2))
```